# Double variable argument list

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, variadic-functions

I need something like this:

```
class Node (left : Node*, right : Node*)
```

I understand the ambiguity of this signature.

Is there a way around it better than the following?

```
class Node (left : Array[Node, right : Array[Node])
val n = new Node (Array(n1, n2), Array(n3))
```

Maybe some kind of separator like this?

```
val n = new Node (n1, n2, Sep, n3)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have multiple argument lists, each of which may have (or just be) one repeated-args parameter:

```
scala> def m1(ints: Int*)(strs: String*): Int = ints.length + strs.length
dm1: (ints: Int*)(strs: String*)Int

scala> m1(1, 2, 3)("one", "two", "three")
res0: Int = 6
```

I ran this in the Scala 2.8 REPL. I don't know a reason it wouldn't work in 2.7, offhand.

Comment: @Łukasz Lew: I was but 9 seconds behind you!

Comment: So I will give you the great green tick of answer :)

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
class Node (left : Node*) (right : Node*)
```

Scala is great!

Answer (score 1):

I dont beleive you can have multiple varargs. You maybe could do something like

```
class Node(left: Node*) {
  def apply(right: Node*) = ...
```

and then you can create `new Node(n1,n2)(n3)`